# Which layer of my application should have integration tests: Controller vs Service VS DAO?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

If my application has three layers
1. Controller
2. Service
3. DAO

Which of the above layers should have integration tests?

Currently, I have covered the controller and service layers with extensive unit test cases, including any validations in the respective layers. Also I have mocked out any dependencies in these layers.

I only have integration tests for my DAO methods, to actually test the DB interaction.

Is this a good approach of having integration tests only for the DAO layer and unit testing all the other layers using mocks wherever required ? Or should I also write integration tests for my controller and service layers? Please share thoughts.

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ might be a better forum to ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test pyramid suggests that you should have very many unit tests, many single-later integration tests, some multi-level integration tests, and a very few full end-to-end tests.

Comment: If a higher-level test gives you more confidence that your application works correctly, you should have it. Writing a unit test for a Controller class helps to test the logic within the Controller itself. Still, this won't tell you whether the REST endpoint this Controller provides actually responds to HTTP requests. So you move up the test pyramid and add a test that checks for exactly that - but nothing more.

Comment: You don't test all the conditional logic and edge cases that your lower-level tests already cover in the higher-level test again. Make sure that the higher-level test focuses on the part that the lower-level tests couldn't cover.

Comment: Above snippet from this blog that I found upon a quick search on test pyramid. https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html . Thanks for suggesting about test pyramid.